# Redirect to page when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a page which have the list of users on my page. What I wanted to do is when I clicked a specific user it will redirect me to the profile of the user I clicked. Now my problem is when I check on inspect element `href` has link but when I tried to click the user nothing happens it doesn't redirect me to the profile page of the user that I click. But when I open it on a new tab of the browser it redirects me to the profile page of the user. Here is my code.

```
var group_id = <?php echo json_encode((isset($_GET['gid'])) ? $_GET['gid'] : false) ;?>;

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'../ajax/group/get_memberlist.php',
    dataType:'JSON',
    data:{
        group_id: group_id
    },
    success:function (data) {
        for (var m = 0; m < data.memberslist.length; m++) {

            var $htmlObject = $($.parseHTML($.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'../htmlstrings/group_memberlist.html',
            cache: false,
            async: false
        }).responseText));
        $htmlObject.attr('user_id',data.memberslist[m].user_id);
        $htmlObject.find('img').attr({'src': (data.memberslist[m].pic) ? '../' + data.memberslist[m].pic : '../assets/img/avatars/avatar-55.png'});
        $htmlObject.find('strong').html(data.memberslist[m].user_fullname);
        $htmlObject.find('#member_position').text(data.memberslist[m].position);
        $htmlObject.find('a').attr('href', 'profile.php?user_id=' + data.memberslist[m].user_id);
            console.log( $htmlObject.find('a').attr('href'));
        $('.member-list').append($htmlObject);
      }
   }
 });
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error in console or elsewhere?

Comment: first try to print/ get alert your `$htmlObject` path, sometimes there should be any problem. Show us the error in console or print the error in that page

Comment: check update... after i use `console.log( $htmlObject.find('a').attr('href'));`  that is what happens on the console..

Comment: can you give me the test link?

Comment: please add "/" before 'profile.php' and try, May be this is the error

Comment: i cant provide a test link right now cause its on my local only.. and also i tried using `/` or `../` or `../../` but still nothing works..